# Can a psychiatrist himself need psychological help after working with a mentally ill patient and how can he protect himself from this?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, clinical-psychology, psychiatry, therapy, health-psychology

A psychiatrist identifies mental disorders and pathologies, diagnoses, treats and prevents them. Process of implementing non-pharmacological psychological correction of the patient’s psycho-emotional state is not just the mutual participation of patient and doctor, but also the mutual influence on each other.

If this is indeed the case, then how to protect the psyche and carry out its hygiene in order to reduce the impact of the patient's mental disorders on the body and mind of the psychiatrist, and how do these methods work from a neuropsychological point of view?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: [How do clinicians control for their own mental disorders?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15866/7001)  Also see: [Are psychologists more immune to psychological problems?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16623/7001) and [Why do therapists need therapy?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26030/7001)

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I found answers to my questions using the links you provided. Thank you.